# Why do meta posts that aren't tagged [bug] or [support] have green check marks?

Tags: discussion

I noticed that if someone is discussing a change of policy, the OP determines which answer appears at top with the green checkmark. Why does the OP select which answer is correct for things affecting the entire community?

Comment: The OP's decision doesn't really change the Devs' decision. If they will, they'll implement something in relation to the discussion. I don't see why the OP's acceptance would be a problem.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani It makes the community think a certain point of view is the top one.

Comment: I don't think it would; specially here, if I'd wanna see if something's *popular*, I'd take a look at the post's score. (Can't see the main number of up/downs though)

Comment: Most people on Meta have a pretty good idea how SE works, including the fact that accepted answers are just the asker's choice. If you've been around SE any real length of time, you've seen questions with wrong and unpopular accepted answers.

Answer (score 8):

Accepting answers is integral part of Stack Exchange, along with voting.

Same way they never hide the voting arrows, they don't hide the check marks.

Same way that votes on Community Wiki posts are mostly meaningless, accepted answer of a meta discussion reflects only the personal view of OP, and not something official.

Can't see anything wrong with any of that.

Comment: Indeed; but as a side note, they hide 'em when the post is locked, but that's another case.

Comment: @M.A.Ramezani only historical lock which is quite rare. Ordinary post lock doesn't hide the arrows, only cause error to appear when trying to click them. :)

Answer (score 4):

> I noticed that if someone is discussing a change of policy, the OP
>   determines which answer appears at top with the green checkmark.

With a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), a user is likely to select the answer which they feel most closely resembles their proposal, and possibly with new/additional ideas.

This is perfectly fine, and doesn't in any way suggest it's an *official* response.

> Why does the OP select which answer is correct for things affecting
>   the entire community?

They don't. The OP selects whichever answer they feel is best for *them*, which is the same on all questions, on all sites, for all tags.

No where on any Stack Exchange site, FAQ, or Help Center does it state that an accepted answer (a green tick) is an *official* response.

---

[discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) questions don't even ask for an official response really.

Don't forget that the sites are ran by community (you and I), certainly as much as they can be. So it's natural for [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) questions to be discussed without an official response.

Us normal users can and do pick the bones out of the ideas.
An official response on a feature-request tends to only come when something is planned or has been implemented, or, for example, if it's a really popular question with a lot of upvotes, staff might respond to show their stance.

Comment: You've exactly mixed up what he's saying: he's asking why questions that are **not** [tag:bug] or [tag:support] have accepted answers.

Comment: @cpast Thanks :) I'm off to learn to read propoerly